# BeautifulSoup4 find() function not working

Tags: python, python-2.7, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I'm trying to extract `Some_Product_Title` from this block of HTML code

```
<div id="titleSection" class="a-section a-spacing-none">
        <h1 id="title" class="a-size-large a-spacing-none">
            <span id="productTitle" class="a-size-large">


                        Some_Product_Title


            </span>
```

The lines below are working fine

```
page = requests.get(URL, headers = headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
```

But the code below is not

```
title = soup.find_all(id="productTitle")
```

Since when I try `print(title)` I get `None` as the console output

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: You probably need to `print(title.text)` to view the text within the tag.

Comment: After doing that, I get `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'` from the console

Comment: Ah, then it seems that your selector is not correctly assigning an element to the `title` variable. I thought maybe it was just some strangeness about how BS prints out a span that doesn't have text at that level of the DOM. Maybe take a second look at `find_all` and try something more like `soup.find(id="productTitle")`

Comment: exactly. I don't understand why my selector is not correctly assigning an element to the title variable

Comment: Hmmm, you can test CSS selectors by searching (Ctrl+F) in the source panel in devtools. Either that, or since the H1 tag contains the text, maybe try selecting that and seeing if you can get the text out that way? Maybe dump the soup to console and make sure you're not being re-directed somewhere without a title tag?

Comment: yeah. trying to get the text from h1 doesn't work either. And when I do `print(soup)` after `soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')` the lines of html code above for `Some_Product_Title` are definitely there.

Comment: Arggghhh! I think I've got it... Can you try to create the soup from `response.text`, not `response.content`? I think BS4 or the html parser aren't expecting a byte stream and so isn't parsing as expected!

Comment: yeah. That returned `None` as well. BUT I think you're on to something. When I take what is printed out onto the console from `print(soup)` and store it as `data = '''<what is printed onto the console>'''` then do `soup2 = BeautifulSoup(data, 'html.parser')` and `title2 = soup2.find(id="productTitle")`, I successfully get `Some_Product_Title` from `print(title2)` so something definitely went wrong in the creation of soup

Comment: OK, good luck! Once you get the soup made, don't forget that `find_all` always returns a list, so index into it before trying to pull the `text`

Answer (score 3):

You're probably having trouble with `.find()` because the site from which you are creating the soup is, in all likelihood, generating its html code via javascript.

If this is the case, to find an element by `id`, you should implement the following:

```
soup1 = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html.parser")
soup2 = BeautifulSoup(soup1.prettify(), "html.parser")
title = soup2.find(id = "productTitle")
```

Comment: Wow. That did it. Thanks!

Comment: I don't understand the need for soup1.prettify() step. Please can you provide some info on why this step is needed?

Comment: @QHarr the creation of the second soup allows you to avoid the issues that come with parsing HTML code that is generated from javascript. The `.prettify()` function enables you to see how the tags are nested in the HTML document.

Comment: Thanks. So prettify is somehow providing missing nested structure?

Comment: @QHarr It is, but `.prettify()` isn't necessary for Beautiful Soup's member functions such as `.find()` to work.  `.prettify()` helps you to se the nested structure when you need to view the HTML document as such.

Answer (score 1):

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = 'https://your-own.address/some-thing'
page = requests.get(URL, headers = headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
title = soup.findAll('',{"id":"productTitle"})
print(*title)
```

Comment: I tried this, but so far, it's not working. I've added more info about my problem above, so please read what I added to see if that changes the viable solution

Comment: @BenJohnson I did some edits. I hope this works for you

Comment: Are you sure that website contains a tag with id `"productionTitle"`?

Answer (score 1):

BS4 has CSS selectors built in so you can use:
`soup.select('#productTitle')`

This would also work:
`title = soup.find_all("span", { "id" : "productTitle" })`

Comment: I tried both of your suggestions, but so far, they're not working. I've added more info about my problem, so please read what I added above and see if that changes the viable solution